# WSO2 Api Manager Working with Third-Parties and external login

Tags: wso2, api-manager, wso2-cloud

we have wso2 api manager v4.1 for our api and web services which calling from our third parties.
we should use oauth2 protocol for calling api.
the problem is: one of the third parties should at first request to api manager and wso2 redirect user to our login page. the user should login in our login page then if success we redirect user with AuthorizationCode in response to third party portal, then third party should send AuthorizationCode to Api manager for get AccessToken and RefreshToken then can call our api and services.
Is there a solution in WSO2 api manager for this workflow?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typical authorization grant code flow. WSO2 does support almost all the standard grant types.

Please refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/grant-types/authorization-code-grant/